# Access SQL sub Query

Tags: sql

I have the following sub query which updates the order header if all Items in the Order Detail Status = 2, however i also have a few records with StatusFK = 4 (deleted) how can i add this into my subquery so that it ignores any StatusFK's of 4?

```
  UPDATE tblOrder
  SET tblOrder.Statusfk = 2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tblOrderDetail
              WHERE tblOrderDetail.OrderFK = tblOrder.OrderPK AND
                    tblOrderDetail.StatusFK <> 2 AND
                    tblOrder.StatusFK);
```

Comment: By adding another condition? AND tblOrderDetail.StatusFK <> 4

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the Anwsers! it was simple in the end.

```
UPDATE tblOrder SET tblOrder.Statusfk = 2
WHERE (((Exists (SELECT 1
              FROM tblOrderDetail
              WHERE tblOrderDetail.OrderFK = tblOrder.OrderPK AND
                    tblOrderDetail.StatusFK <> 2 AND
                    tblOrder.StatusFK AND tblOrderDetail.StatusFK <> 4
             ))=False));
```